# FTP log creation

Tags: iis, ftp, log-files

Does anyone know if by default FTP logs in IIS are created every day at midnight (if set to daily) or only if there is activity against the FTP site?  We have an automated process that is supposed to be checking the FTP site every few minutes, but a log file is not always created.  Would IIS just create a log file regardless if there was nothing happening?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, IIS does not create a log file if there is no activity during the rotation cycle.  I can't find where it specifically mentions this for FTP, but [**here's the KB**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291279) that says it specifically for web (IIS 4-6 anyway).

Comment: Thanks squillman that KB really helps.  The programmer claims this process is working, but a log file is not always being created.  I hope this shows him it is not always running.

Comment: To confirm what squillman says, from my own FTP server, there are no log files created when there is no activity.